# replacing $variable output in powershell

Tags: powershell

Using function i'm getting output like this:

```
User                                                                                                         
----                                                                                                         
Domain\Username
```

But when I'm trying to replace the "Domain\" in output

```
$f -replace 'Domain\\'
```

I'm getting this:

```
@{User=Username}
```

I'm using bad function or is something else is going wrong?

Comment: `$f.User=$f.User -replace 'Domain\\';$f`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$f.User -replace 'Domain\\', ''
```

instead of this -

```
$f -replace 'Domain\'
```

Your output from your variable is showing you the answer. You had an object with a `user` property as supposed to the string you thought you were working on.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is an object with a property `User`. If you just use `-replace` on the object you're basically converting the object to a string (`@{User=Domain\Username}`) and replacing `Domain\` in that string. Use the operator on the property `User` to remove the substring from the value of that property:

```
$f.User -replace 'Domain\\'
```